# How to get tweet using AppleScript

Tags: macos, twitter, applescript

I want to acquire the latest tweet in AppleScript.
However, variables of "status" can't save.
How to store the tweet status object?

It is working :

```
tell application "Twitter"
  set tw to text of item 1 of statuses of home timeline of current account
end tell
```

It is not working :

```
tell application "Twitter"
  set tw to item 1 of statuses of home timeline of current account
  set txt to text of tw
end tell
```

Comment: Can you share the code? It's impossible to help you without the code...

Comment: Sorry, I'm fixed format of the question text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late in the day to mention it, but take a look at my app "[Twitter Scripter](http://www.mousedown.net/mouseware/TwitterScripter.html)" available free on the Mac AppStore.

It's a faceless background application designed to make access to the Twitter API from AppleScript trivial. It piggy backs the native Twitter support in OS X (10.8+) and so you you don't need to handle any authentication yourself. You can retrieve responses from the twitter API as structured AppleScript records.

For example:

```
tell app "Twitter Scripter"
  set myTwitterAccount to item 1 of (available accounts) as string
  -- User timeline: This function retrieves the Tweets for a given user name
  fetch user timeline for username "mousedownsoft" using account myTwitterAccount with excluding replies and including retweets
end
```

Comment: Sadly defunct now, since Apple deprecated ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter

Answer (score 1):

There's something weird with Twitter.app's AppleScript support, but if you only need to get multiple properties, you can use a tell block or parallel assignment.

```
tell application "Twitter"
    tell item 1 of statuses of home timeline of current account
        set t to text
        set u to url
        properties
    end tell
    -- set {t, u} to {text, url} of item 1 of statuses of home timeline of current account
end tell
```

Or could you use the API instead? This should work if you run `sudo gem install twitter` and register an application at [dev.twitter.com](https://dev.twitter.com).

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'twitter'

Twitter.configure { |config|
    config.consumer_key = ""
    config.consumer_secret = ""
    config.oauth_token = ""
    config.oauth_token_secret = ""
}

p Twitter.home_timeline.first.text
p Twitter.home_timeline.first.inspect
```